# meromorphic function with a pole on the unit circle diverges

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f$ be a meromorphic function in a neighborhood of the closed unit disk $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and 
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n $$
for $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Prove that if $f$ has a pole on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ then the above power series diverges at any $z \in \mathbb{T}$.

Attempt at solution :
My first observation was that if I can prove this claim when the pole is at a specific point like $z = 1$ on $\mathbb{T}$, then using rotation the claim will be valid for any arbitrary point on $\mathbb{T}$. So I assumed 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = \frac{g(z)}{(z-1)^k}$$ 
with $g(z)$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Even with the further simplification of assuming k = 1, I could only prove that $\lim_{n-> \infty} a_n = g(1)$ which is finite. Can someone please help with the solution.

Comment: Are you sure the statement holds? $\sum_n z^n/n$ has a pole in $1$ and can be easilly extended, but the series converges everywhere on the unit circle except 1.

Comment: @PeterFranek Your function $-\mathrm{Log}(1-z)$ isn't meromorphic on any neighborhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$

Comment: This does not hold for $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: @Mustafa Except the series does diverge on the circle in that case. The function itself doesn't, but a series need not converge wherever the function is analytic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to show that the coefficients $a_n$ cannot converge to $0$.  Now suppose that $|a_k| \leq \varepsilon$ for $k \geq m$.  Then for $z\in\mathbb{D}$ $$|f(z)|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{1-|z|}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}|a_k|.$$  This implies that if $a_k$ converges to $0$ then $\lim_{|z|\to 1}(1-|z|)|f(z)|=0$. In particular $f$ cannot have a pole on $\mathbb{T}$ in this case.

Comment: This seems to only prove that it has at most simple poles. Poles of order one seem unaffected by this logic, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Did you try what happens near a simple pole?

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Could that last limit be $0$ in case of a (simple) pole?

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, I see. Basically it's the same contradiction I drew in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If what you say you've proven is correct, then you are done. If the series converged at some $z$ on the boundary, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=0=g(1)$, contradicting that the order of the pole is $k$.

Comment: What I have proven is when f has a simple pole at $z=1$, then $g(z) = (1-z)\sum a_n z^n = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{n-1}-a_n) z^n$. That is $g(z) = a_0 + \lim_{k->\infty} \sum_1^k(a_{n-1}-a_n)z^n$. So for $z=1$ we have $g(1) = \lim_{k->\infty}a_k$. Hence I think I can only conclude that since this gives $g(1) =0$, hence f cannot have a simple pole at 1. But how can I prove that there cannot be poles of higher orders?

Comment: @Sourav I think I missed the part where you said you were looking at one special case. I'd like to say you can do an induction, but that seems unpleasant at best here. Try WimC's answer, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the the pole is at $z_0=1$. 
Put $\displaystyle f(z)=g(z)+\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{u_k}{(z-1)^k}$ where $\displaystyle h(z)=\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{u_k}{(z-1)^k}$ is the singular part of $f$ at $1$ ($u_s\not =0)$. Hence $\displaystyle g(z)=\sum b_n z^n$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, thus its radius of convergence is $>1$. Thus $b_n\to 0$ if $n\to \infty$. Note also that $\displaystyle h(z)=\sum P(n)z^n$, where $\displaystyle P(x)=\alpha_{s-1}x^{s-1}+...$ is a polynomial of degree $s-1$ $(\alpha_{s-1}\not =0)$. If $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$, we have hence $a_n=b_n+P(n)$. We immediately get that $|a_n|\sim |\alpha_{s-1}|n^{s-1}$, and for $z\in \mathbb{T}$ that $|a_n z^n|\sim |\alpha_{s-1}|n^{s-1}$ if $n\to +\infty$. Hence $a_n z^n$ does not go to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, and the series is divergent.