# Divergence everywhere on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ has the radius of convergence $R$. If there exists a pole of $f(x)$ on $\partial B(0,R)$, then the power series diverges everywhere $\partial B(0,R)$.

---

I am trying to show that if $f$ is expanded at $Re^{it}/2$, the radius of convergence is equal to $R/2$, and this hold for every $t\in [0, 2\pi)$. If so, then the power series diverge everywhere on the circle. But that seems not the correct way of doing this, as I cannot prove $\limsup_{n\to \infty} (f^{(n)}(Re^{it}/2)/n!)^{1/n}=2/R$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is that a power series? If it is, why not write it in the usual way?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876655/meromorphic-function-with-a-pole-on-the-unit-circle-diverges